# Come back to activity from maps intent espresso - UI testing

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, ui-automation, android-espresso

I am using Espresso for UI testing. I wanna test a feature that Intent the app to the google maps app and come back to the same activity. The Intent is done successfully and the google maps is opened but i dont have control over the maps app and `Espresso.pressBack();`  is not working. Is there a way to press back button using espresso ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
```

and then

```
UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
mDevice.pressBack();
```

Which I found here: [Espresso.pressBack() does not call onBackPressed()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861182/espresso-pressback-does-not-call-onbackpressed)

However, for this use case, pressing back probably isn't the workaround you want. Consider stubbing your intent instead with [`Intent.intending(Matcher)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/Intents.html#intending(org.hamcrest.Matcher<android.content.Intent>))so that the test doesn't leave your app.